# Five Enigmatic Images

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle

(There is no "flavour text" for the puzzle, but I need to post some words for StackExchange to accept my question.)

[image: Five images]

Comment: My first puzzle. Suggestions/corrections welcome.

Comment: This was a nice puzzle! A few minor inconsistencies in how it worked, but it was a cute and fun idea.

Comment: @Deusovi: I concede the inconsistencies. I couldn't find a way to eliminate them, but yeah, I found it cute, so I proceeded anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each of these images

> clues the sound of the word "tack" [or something similar to it -- the vowel sound can be different], followed by a letter sound.

We have:

> - a taxi ("tack-C")
>  - George Takei ("tack-A")
>  - Liam Neeson in Taken ("tack-N" -- vowel sound is different here but it's written with an 'a' still)
>  - a taco ("tack-O", if you heavily Americanise the pronunciation)
>  - and Weird Al in Tacky ("tack-E").
>
>  So the answer is **CANOE**.